# Can't call super.toString

Tags: java, oop, object-to-string

I tried calling the super.toString of the superclass in the subclass Manager, but it won't work. I want the output to be like this:

```
current data:
#Person (ID=1):
firstname: NN                  
lastname: NN                  
email: unknown
date of birth: 01.01.1970
annual pay: 0.00
#Manager:
annual base pay: 0.00
bonus: 0.00

firstname: lastname: email: date of birth: enter date (y m d)
```

but all I get is without displaying attributes from the superclass:

```
firstname:
lastname:
email:
date of birth: enter date (y m d)
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated thanks

```
 public class Person {

            private String fn;
            private String ln;
            private String email;
            private Date dob;
            private static int nextID=1;
            private final int ID=nextID++;

            Person(){
                this.fn = "NN";
                this.ln = "NN";
                this.email = "unknown";
                this.dob = new Date();
            }

            public String getFn(){
                return fn;
            }

            public void setFn(String fn){
                if(fn==null || fn.equals("")){
                    return;
                }

                this.fn=fn;
            }

            public String getLn(){
                return ln;
            }

            public void setLn(String ln){
                if(ln==null || ln.equals("")){
                    return;
                }

                this.ln=ln;
            }


            public String getEmail(){
                return email;
            }

            public void setEmail(String email){
                if(ln==null || ln.equals("")){
                    return;
                }
                if(!email.contains("@")){
                    return;
                }

                this.email=email;
            }

            public Date getDob(){
                return new Date(dob);
            }

            public void setDob(Date dob){

                if(dob==null){
                    return;
                }

                this.dob= new Date(dob);
            }

            public String toString(){
                return String.format("current data:\n#Person (ID=%d)\nfirstname: %s\nlastname: %s\nemail: %s\ndate of birth: %s\nannual pay: %d", getID(), getFn(), getLn(), getEmail(), getDob(), getAnnualPay());
            }

            public int getAnnualPay(){
                return 0;
            }

            public void editPerson() {
                //firstname: lastname: email: date of birth: enter date (y m d)
                TextIO.putln("firstname:");
                this.fn = TextIO.getln();

                TextIO.putln("lastname:");
                this.ln = TextIO.getln();

                TextIO.putln("email:");
                this.email = TextIO.getln();

                TextIO.putln("date of birth: enter date (y m d)");
                this.dob = new Date();
            }

            public int getID(){
                return ID;
            }



        }



        public class Manager extends Person {

            private int annualBasePay;
            private int bonus;

            public Manager(){
                this.annualBasePay = 0;
                this.bonus = 0;
            }

            public int getAnnualPay(){
                return annualBasePay+bonus;
            }

            public void editPerson(){
                this.toString();
                super.editPerson();
            }

            public void setAnnualBasePay(int annualBasePay){
                if(annualBasePay<=0){
                    return;
                }
                this.annualBasePay=annualBasePay;
            }

            public int getAnnualBasePay(){
                return annualBasePay;
            }

            public void setBonus(int bonus){
                if(bonus<0){
                    return;
                }
                this.bonus=bonus;
            }

            public int getBonus(){
                return bonus;
            }

            public String toString(){
                //super.toString();
                return String.format("%s/n#Manager:\nannual base pay: %d\nbonus: %d",super.toString(),getAnnualBasePay(), getBonus());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Calling `super.toString()` doesn't do anything, you need to do something with the return value.

Comment: I did. I returned what I want to display on the string to the toString fucntion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about super.toString(). Just invoke the getters for the properties you need from  Person.

Comment: Thanks Andres, but not working. The issue is that I am not getting the values of attributes from the Super class as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Adjust:

```
public String toString(){
                super.toString();
                return String.format("%s/n#Manager:\nannual base pay: %d\nbonus: %d",super.toString(),getAnnualBasePay(), getBonus());
        }
```

to

```
 public String toString(){

            return super.toString()+"\n"+String.format("%s/n#Manager:\nannual base pay: %d\nbonus: %d",super.toString(),getAnnualBasePay(), getBonus());
        }
```